# Why does closing a sftp client not close the whole SSH connection

Tags: go, sftp

I have an SFTP client which connect over the ssh and transfer files. My client just reported to me that the SFTP client isn't closing the connection that has opened.

I examine my code and found that I'm calling the SFTP `Close()` function. I created a sample example to test my theory

```
func main() {
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "admin",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("admin123"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    for {
        client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "192.168.0.100:22", config)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Failed to dial: ", err)
        }
        sftpClient, err := sftp.NewClient(client)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("SFTP client got error %s", err)
        }

        results, err := sftpClient.Glob("/Users/admin/Desktop/sftp/*")

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("GLOB error: ", err)
        }

        for _, r := range results {
            log.Println(r)
        }
        fmt.Println("We are closing connection ..")
        if err := sftpClient.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } 

        time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
    }
```

I'm closing the connection just after the `fmt.Println` statement.

What I inspected from the `netstat` is indeed the connection `are not closed`.

I decided to close the `ssh.Dial` client and **it worked** with a little bit of change in code

```
   if err := sftpClient.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
            client.Close()
        }
```

So whatdoes is **SFTP Close() fn** does then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What does `sftpClient.Close()` do (as distinct from `client.Close()`?

It closes only the sftp connection over your SSH transport, but leaves that transport open.

#### Why is that useful?

Because you might want to access *other* services over that transport -- run a shell command, or an interactive session with a terminal, or so forth -- without needing to reauthenticate and pay other setup costs a second time.

#### Can I see this functionality used "in real life", without Go?

Sure! [In OpenSSH, use the `ControlMaster` / `ControlSocket` options](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) to cache a single transport per remote destination and run multiple clients over it, and you'll have the same behavior your Go program was doing here (run an OpenSSH `sftp` command, exit it, and the transport will still be open, waiting for another `sftp` command, a `ssh` command, &c. going to the same server to reuse it).